# NEST Elasticsearch query value between 2 field names

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I want to convert the following sql query into an elasticsearch NEST query:

```
select * from Table1 where 20 between minAge and maxAge
```

So far this is what my nest query looks like ("20" is value from client):

```
var result5 = client.Search<Person>(b => b
        .Filter(ff => ff
                .Range(n => n
                    .OnField(f => f.minAge)
                    .Greater(20)
                )
            )
        .Filter(ff => ff
                .Range(n => n
                    .OnField(f => f.maxAge)
                    .Lower(???)  // how do I specify max value as fieldname?
                )
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   .Filter(ff => ff
            .Range(n => n
                .OnField(f => f.minAge)
                .Greater(x)
            ) && ff
            .Range(n => n
                .OnField(f => f.maxAge)
                .Lower(x)
            )
        )
```

In this way you have  x -> between minAge and maxAge. So x must be greater then minAge and lower then maxAge in the same time. Hope it helps!

Comment: .Lower(x) will be translated into [maxAge] must be less than 20 which is incorrect. Using .Greater(x) is the correct solution.

Comment: Both Ranges should be using Greater(x). Using Lower(x) on [minAge] will mean 20 must be smaller than [minAge] which doesn't match the sql query.

Comment: I will test this. As you say has no sense. If u use greater for both of them the x must be greater then a small value ( minAge ) and a greater value ( maxAge ) in the same time ... I think my initial post was good.

Comment: you're absolutely right. I kept running my query and forgot to add the [&&] symbol like you did in your query which meant my first filter kept getting overwritten by the second one. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This sql mean that minAge<20 and maxAge>20, so the nest query is:

```
    var result5 = client.Search<Person>(b => b
    .Filter(ff => ff
            .Range(n => n
                .OnField(f => f.minAge)
                .Lower(20)
            ) && ff
            .Range(n => n
                .OnField(f => f.maxAge)
                .Greater(20)
            )
        )
    ;
```